# how to print arithmetic example in python below?

Tags: python

i'm trying to generate the following arithmetic example:

> 1 * 8 + 1 = 9
>
> 12* 8 + 2 = 98
>
> 123 * 8 + 3 = 987
>
> 1234 * 8 + 4 = 9876
>
> ......

but, after thinking, i can only write code like this:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in range(1, x):
        print(y, end='')
    print(" * 8")
```

and the output is like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjDhy.png)

Please give some hint or answer, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the desired output

```
nums = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
first = ''

for x in range(9):
    first += nums[x]
    equa = first + ' * 8 + '  + nums[x]
    print(equa + ' = ', eval(equa))
```